# setWallpaper in Android after app terminated

Tags: android, react-native, background-process

I'm able to setWallpaper in Android while app is in foreground and in background using background task. However I'm not able to set the wallpaper when the app is terminated (cleared from the recents). Is this possible, if so how can achieve this in react native? With expo or without.

Comment: do you need the code for react native or java/kotlin?

Comment: Code for react native(with Expo or without)

Comment: sorry bro can't help with react native.